# Drag and Drop Behavior Inconsistent between Images in Safari

Tags: css, angular, safari, frontend, drag-and-drop

In this video, I'll be demonstrating an inconsistent drag-and-drop behavior that I've observed specifically in Safari. As you'll see, when dragging the motor.png for the second time, the  element is unexpectedly dragged along with it. However, this issue doesn't occur with the king.png. If you've encountered similar issues or have any insights, please comment below. [Issue happened video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qct4qZ3vzaayB6ECLuakFJ5s_qJbk-NR/view?usp=share_link)

I'm experiencing an odd behavior in Safari related to the drag-and-drop feature. I have a simple game board where I can drag images. Here's a simplified version of my HTML:

```
<div id="gameboard">
  <div class="square beige">
    <img width="200" height="200" src="assets/images/motor.png" alt="King piece" id="king" class="chess-piece" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div class="square brown"></div>
  <div class="square beige"></div>
</div>
<p id="info">Deneme</p>
```

```
  king:any;
  squares:any;
  beingDragged:any;
  this.king = document. querySelector(' .chess-piece')
  this.squares = document. querySelectorAll('.square')
  this.king.addEventListener ('dragstart', this.dragStart)
  this.squares.forEach ((square:any) => {
    square.addEventListener('drop', this.dragDrop);
    square.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragOver);
  });
  dragStart = (e:any) => {
    this.beingDragged = e.target;
  }

  dragOver = (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  dragDrop = (e:any) => {
    e.target.append(this.beingDragged)
  }
```

The issue I'm facing is specific to Safari:

When I drag the motor.png for the second time, the  element gets dragged along with it.
When I drag another image, say king.png, this behavior is not observed and the

element never gets dragged.
This inconsistency only occurs in Safari. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue or can provide insight into why this is happening? Any suggestions or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Here the images that I talked about it;
[image]

[image]